# chat login not working?(quickblox)

Tags: ios, swift, chat, quickblox, mbaas

I have been using the same code to login the user to chat

```
  var user = QBUUser()   
  user.ID = session.userID    
   user.login = "123456"
   user.password = "password" 

 QBChat.instance().loginWithUser(user)
```

But for the last 5 days i get an error that states that the user has to login to chat.

> 2015-08-11 12:13:48.690 buyzar[3063:73416] -[QBChat(Deprecated) sendMessage:] -> return. You have to be logged in in order to use Chat API

Is there any change i am not aware of?

Comment: Hi Kader, how did you get the code, Is it available in quickblox, I could not find documentation on swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have a valid session first. Here is the code that I am using and it works perfectly as you use the completion handle to ensure that the user is logged in before you do anything else.

```
//MARK: - Completions
var logincompletion: ((success: Bool) -> ())? 
//MARK: - Login

func loginUser(login: String, password: String, completion:
    ((success: Bool) -> ())? = nil) {
        self.logincompletion = completion
        var parameters: QBSessionParameters = QBSessionParameters()

        parameters.userEmail = login
        parameters.userPassword = password

        QBRequest.createSessionWithExtendedParameters(parameters, successBlock: { (response: QBResponse!, session: QBASession!) -> Void in

            var currentUser = QBUUser()
            currentUser.ID = session.userID
            currentUser.password = password
            currentUser.login = login 

            QBChat.instance().addDelegate(self)
            QBChat.instance().loginWithUser(currentUser)

            }) { (response: QBResponse!) -> Void in
                if self.logincompletion != nil {
                    self.logincompletion!(success: false)
                }
        }
}
```

Here is an example of me calling this code:

```
ChatManager.SharedInstance.loginUser(UserManager.SharedInstance.user!.email, password: UserManager.SharedInstance.user!.account_id) { (success) -> () in   
        println("Logged into QuickBlox: \(success)")
        if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
            if appDelegate.deviceTokenData != nil {
                var deviceIdentifier = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString
                QBRequest.registerSubscriptionForDeviceToken(appDelegate.deviceTokenData, uniqueDeviceIdentifier: deviceIdentifier, successBlock: { (response: QBResponse!, session: [AnyObject]!) -> Void in
                    println("registered for push")
                    }) { (error: QBError!) -> Void in
                        println("could not reigster for push: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show it being called? You say "you use the completion handle to ensure that the user is logged in before you do anything else" ...

Comment: Have edited the answer to show it. I am doing this on the dashboard of my app, then when you tap on a chat it is all ready to go